# Not able to render HighChart to a smaller div

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am rendering a bunch of High Charts to different divs. I'm trying to achieve a scenario where I show all the charts on the home page in smaller divs. One screen shot of all the charts together. I couldn't do it dynamically so I have different files for all the charts. One copy of all 6 charts (graph1.js, graph2.js ..) named as tinygraph1.js, tinygraph2.js and so on. These tinygraphs are the smaller version of graphs.

My problem is I can render 3 of them all fine by just changing the variable   "renderTo".

```
renderTo: graph1 changedTo renderTo: tinygraph1
```

Its not working for 2 of the graphs when everything is exactly same as other four. Any suggestion/idea is appreciated.

If more details are required let me know. I have never used High Charts before so I apologize if I didnot explain properly.

Comment: What part is not working? Any errors in console? Do all rendTo DIVs exist?

Comment: Can you provide a live demo in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Rendering the graph to 'tinygraph' divs is not working out

Comment: Have you the same chart configuration object for each chart? Working demo will help us to check your scenario, deeper.